# Windows Experience Index still low for Hard Disk with New SSD

Tags: windows-7, performance, ssd

My Windows Experience Index (Windows 7 64 bit) is still a 5.9 for Hard Disk - the same that it was with my 7200 rpm Hard Disk - although now I have a 160GB Intel 320 series SSD...  See the image below as well.

Any ideas what my issue is here?  I am using "iastor" as my AHCI driver, and everything is aligned ok (according to AS SSD)...  I'm clueless why its still so low...

[image: Intel SSD Toolbox Status]

Comment: To rule out a trivial case: You updated the values by clicking *Re-run the assessment*, right?

Comment: @Dennis Yes sir! haha.

Comment: What are you seeing as the sustained read/write speeds of the drive?

Comment: @steampowered it feels really fast, I mean it's definately faster than the old drive - no question...  how can I check the sustained speeds?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Windows Vista, 5.9 is the highest score.

from: [Microsoft](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/What-is-the-Windows-Experience-Index)

Comment: Just added more info. (Windows 7 64 bit)